# Initial position of a node while using PathTransition in JavaFX

Tags: javafx

This is my first question here, so hello everyone!
I am a beginner in programming, writing a "game" in JavaFX for fun, but also to learn.
I know the basics, but what baffles me are my problems with understanding node positioning.
I looked through other related SO and JavaFX documentation, but still don't get it. Here is my problem - I replicated it this very simplified piece of code (here I am using rectangles for simplicity, the actual game uses a class extending ImageView, but I don't think this makes any difference):

```
package spawntest;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;
import javafx.animation.AnimationTimer;
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.KeyValue;
import javafx.animation.PathTransition;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Line;
import javafx.scene.shape.Polyline;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class SpawnTest extends Application {

    public final static int APP_WIDTH = 400;
    public final static int APP_HEIGHT = 600;

    private Scene scene;
    private AnimationTimer timer;
    private Pane root = new Pane();
    private int counter = 0, spawnFrequency;
    private long lastShot = 0;
    private boolean goLeft, goRight, isShooting;
    private Rectangle rectangle;
    private Rectangle player = new Rectangle(20, 20, Color.GREENYELLOW);

    List<Rectangle> rectangles = new ArrayList();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        scene = new Scene(root, APP_WIDTH, APP_HEIGHT);
        stage.setTitle("Tester");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setResizable(false);
        stage.show();
        gameLoop();
        root.getChildren().add(player);
        player.relocate(APP_WIDTH / 2, APP_HEIGHT - 50);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    private void gameLoop() {
        Group group = new Group();
        controls();

        timer = new AnimationTimer() {
            @Override
            public void handle(long now) {
                ++counter;
                spawner(60 * 5);

                int dx = 0, dy = 0;
                if (goLeft) {
                    dx = -5;
                }
                if (goRight) {
                    dx = +5;
                }
                if (isShooting) {
                    shoot();
                }
                movePlayer((int) player.getLayoutX() + dx, (int) player.getLayoutY() + dy);
            }
        };
        timer.start();
    }

    private void controls() {
        scene.setOnKeyPressed((KeyEvent event) -> {
            KeyCode key = event.getCode();
            switch (key) {
                case LEFT:
                    goLeft = true;
                    break;
                case RIGHT:
                    goRight = true;
                    break;
                case SPACE:
                    isShooting = true;
                    break;
            }
        });

        scene.setOnKeyReleased((KeyEvent event) -> {

            KeyCode key = event.getCode();
            switch (key) {
                case LEFT:
                    goLeft = false;
                    break;
                case RIGHT:
                    goRight = false;
                    break;
                case SPACE:
                    isShooting = false;
                    break;
            }
        });
    }

    private void spawner(int spawnFrequency) {
        if (counter % spawnFrequency == 0) {
            gameObjectRandomizer();
        }
    }

    private void shoot() {
        int delay = 100;
        if (lastShot == 0 || System.currentTimeMillis() - lastShot > delay) {
            Rectangle r = missile();
            r.relocate(player.getLayoutX(), player.getLayoutY());
            root.getChildren().add(r);
            lastShot = System.currentTimeMillis();
        }
    }

    public Rectangle missile() {
        Rectangle r = new Rectangle(4, 20, Color.GREY);
//        r.setX(player.getLayoutX());
//        r.setY(player.getLayoutY());
        rectangles.add(r);
        Polyline pLine = new Polyline();
        pLine.getPoints().addAll(new Double[]{
            player.getLayoutX(), player.getLayoutY(),
            player.getLayoutX() - 20.0, player.getLayoutY() + 10.0,
            player.getLayoutX() - 20.0, -r.getHeight()
        });
        PathTransition pt = new PathTransition();
        pt.setNode(r);
        pt.setDuration(Duration.millis(2500));
        pt.setPath(pLine);
        pt.play();
        pt.setOnFinished(event -> {
        });
        return r;
    }

    private void gameObjectRandomizer() {
        int randomize = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(2);
        switch (randomize) {
            case 0:
                rectangle = new Rectangle(40, 40, Color.CADETBLUE);
                root.getChildren().add(rectangle);
                rectangle.relocate(Math.random() * APP_WIDTH, 0);
                System.out.println("Initial location: " + rectangle.getLayoutX() + ", " + rectangle.getLayoutY());
                rectangles.add(rectangle);
                timelineAnimation(rectangle);
                break;
            case 1:
                rectangle = new Rectangle(40, 40, Color.CORNFLOWERBLUE);
                root.getChildren().add(rectangle);
                rectangle.relocate(Math.random() * APP_WIDTH, 0);
//                rectangle.setX(Math.random() * APP_WIDTH);
//                rectangle.setY(0);
                System.out.println("Initial location: " + rectangle.getLayoutX() + ", " + rectangle.getLayoutY());
                rectangles.add(rectangle);
                pathTransitionAnimation(rectangle);
                break;
        }
    }

    private void movePlayer(int x, int y) {
        if ((x >= 0 - (player.getWidth() / 2) && x <= APP_WIDTH - (player.getWidth() / 2))
                && (y >= 0 && y <= APP_HEIGHT)) {
            player.relocate(x, y);
        }
    }

    private Timeline timelineAnimation(Rectangle rectangle) {
        Timeline timeline = new Timeline();
        KeyFrame kf1 = new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(0),
                new KeyValue(rectangle.layoutYProperty(), 0));
        KeyFrame kf2 = new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(5000),
                new KeyValue(rectangle.layoutYProperty(), APP_HEIGHT + rectangle.getHeight()));
        timeline.getKeyFrames().addAll(kf1, kf2);
        timeline.play();
        System.out.println("Timeline used. Coords: " + rectangle.getLayoutX() + ", " + rectangle.getLayoutY());
        return timeline;
    }

    private PathTransition pathTransitionAnimation(Rectangle rectangle) {

        Line line = new Line(rectangle.getLayoutX(), rectangle.getLayoutY(),
                rectangle.getLayoutX(), APP_HEIGHT + rectangle.getHeight());
        PathTransition pt = new PathTransition();
        pt.setNode(rectangle);
        pt.setDuration(Duration.millis(5000));
        pt.setPath(line);
        pt.play();
        System.out.println("PathTransition used. Coords: " + rectangle.getLayoutX() + ", " + rectangle.getLayoutY());
        return pt;
    }

}
```

There are 2 types of "enemies" selected randomly (by means of gameObjectRandomizer()) and spawned at random X coords by using relocate(). One is animated by means of a timeline and works ok. The second however is animated by a PathTransition; it appears for a brief moment at the position passed in the relocate() method, but then the animation is started from a completely different X position (seems like a its getLayoutX() * 2). Why is that?

Another thing is at the bottom you have a "player" rectangle. Out of curiosity I also used pathTransition to animate the "missiles" launched by a spacebar; in this code they appear briefly at the player's layoutX and layoutY, but then their position is shifted way outside the scene.

I also tried to use the setX() and setY() methods (commented out in the code) to set the missiles' initial position; it sort of works: they appear at the player's side and are animated from there, but if I add some value, say (setX() + 20), it again appears at (setX() + 20) for a brief moment, and gets animated from the player's getLayoutX() and getLayoutY() position.

From my understanding first I should add a node to a root (or any other Pane), set its initial coords with relocate and then animate it, right? If so, could you push me a bit in the right direction to help me understand what I am doing wrong?

PS. sorry if that very nooby:)

Comment: A `PathTransition` varied the `translateX` and `translateY` properties, not the `layoutX` and `layoutY` properties. So you should start your transition at the current value of the translate properties (which are probably zero).

Comment: @James_D, thanks a lot... I'm dumb, I read your response to similar question, but somehow forget to take it into account, sorry!

Now it works, thought there's still a shift in the coords after the animation starts. 
I noticed the shift is exactly equal to half of the rectangle's width and height. 
So if I use  rectangle.getTranslateX() + rectangle.getWidth()/2 and rectangle.getTranslateY() + rectangle.getHeight()/2, as starting coords of the path transition that works just perfectly. 

Why is that shift happening?